# In R, when is smart to formaly declare a data.frame?

Tags: r

In other R code, it is common to see data.frame declared before a loop is started.
Suppose I have data frame data1 with 2000 rows.
And in a loop, I am via web service looping over data1 to create a new data.frame data2. (Please don't recommend not using a loop).
And in data2$result and data2$pubcount I need to store different values for each of the 2000 data1 items.

Do I HAVE to declare before the loop

```
data2=data.frame()
```

and do I have to tell R how many rows and what columns I will later use? I know that columns can be added without declaring. What about rows. Is there advantage in doing:

```
data2<-data.frame(id=data1$id)
```

I would like to do only what I absolutely HAVE to declare and do.
Why the empty declaration gives error once in the loop?

later edit: Speed and memory is not of issue. 10s vs. 30s makes no difference and I have a under 100MB data and big PC (8GB). Matrix is not an option since the data is numbers and text (mixed), so I have to use non-matrix.

Comment: Why don't you profile the difference between pre-allocating memory (which a `data.frame()` does not do as you have no content or dimensions) and not doing it?

Comment: You can do it in a loop without defining the number of rows and columns beforehand, by using `rbind`. But what is being done in each iteration? (How is `pubcount` calculated, for example?) That does make a difference

Comment: If you don't want alternatives to an explicit loop I would suggest alternatives to a `data.frame`, e.g., it is probably a good idea to use a simple `list` instead or even better to use a (pre-allocated) `matrix` (if you only have one data type).

Comment: Why are you against pre-allocation?

Comment: On a side note, you can usually avoid for loops with vectorized functions such as those in the apply family, but you would have to give more info for anyone to make such a suggestion.

Comment: @NathanG `*apply` functions are just loops in disguise (which does not mean they aren't often preferable to a `for` loop).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this:

```
df <- data.frame(a=numeric(n),b=character(n))

for (i in 1:n) {

#<do stuff>
df[i,1] <- ...
df[i,2] <- ...

}
```

You should avoid manipulation of data.frames in a loop, since subsetting of data.frames is a slow operation:

```
a <- numeric(n)   
b <- character(n) 

for (i in 1:n) {

#<do stuff>
a[i] <- ...
b[i] <- ...

}
df <- data.frame(a,b)
```

Of course, there are often better ways than a `for` loop. But it is strongly recommended to avoid growing objects (and I wont teach you how to do that). Pre-allocate as shown here.

Why should you pre-allocate? Because growing objects in a loop is sloooowwwww and that's one of the main reasons why people think loops in R are slow.